# Nested Sub Query for SQL MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT [doc type]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber     
     , SUM([SumOpenAmount]) As TotalOpenAmount          
FROM 
      (SELECT d.[customer number] & d.[membership number] AS CustMemb
            , d.[customer number]
            , agg.[doc type]
            , SUM(agg.[TotalSubOpenAmount]) AS SumOpenAmount
        FROM  (SELECT [doc type]
                    , [customer number]
                    , SUM([open amount]) AS TotalSubOpenAmount
               FROM   data
               WHERE  [doc type] = 'RU' 
               GROUP BY [doc type]
                      , [customer number]
              ) agg
        INNER JOIN [data] d                                   
           ON  d.[customer number] = agg.[customer number]
        GROUP  BY d.[customer number] & d.[membership number]
                , d.[customer number]
                , agg.[doc type]
      ) AS sub
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

I need to add in:

To SUM the Open Amount where the Open Amount > 0 AND then SUM the Open Amount where the Open Amount is < 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Try a conditional sum:

```
SELECT [doc type]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
     , SUM(IIF([open_amount]>0, [open_amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([open_amount]<0, [open_amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
FROM 
      (SELECT d.[customer number] & d.[membership number] AS CustMemb
            , d.[customer number]
            , agg.[doc type]
            , SUM(agg.[TotalSubOpenAmount]) AS SumOpenAmount
        FROM  (SELECT [doc type]
                    , [customer number]
                    , SUM([open amount]) AS TotalSubOpenAmount
               FROM   data
               WHERE  [doc type] = 'RU' 
               GROUP BY [doc type]
                      , [customer number]
              ) agg
        INNER JOIN [data] d                                   
           ON  d.[customer number] = agg.[customer number]
        GROUP  BY d.[customer number] & d.[membership number]
                , d.[customer number]
                , agg.[doc type]
      ) AS sub
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

You need to fetch the open amount field first.

```
SELECT [doc type]
     , [customer number]
     , COUNT([customer number]) As CountCustomerNumber
     , SUM(IIF([open_amount]>0, [open_amount], 0)) AS sum_open_amount_pos   
     , SUM(IIF([open_amount]<0, [open_amount], 0)) As sum_open_amount_neg         
FROM 
      (
-- This is the part in which the field open_amount should be fetched.
) AS sub
GROUP  BY [doc type]
        , [customer number]
HAVING COUNT([customer number]) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. MS Access is throwing a Syntax Error message and highlighting the 'WHEN'.

Comment: Maybe it was bracket related? I've edited my question.

Comment: I've just realised that case when does not exist in MS Access. Try the newly edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is looking for a parameter input for open_amount.

Comment: Is that with or without brackets?

Comment: @JohnDaly you need the open amount field in the inline query in order to be able to use it.

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: @JohnDaly you have aliased it 'sub'

Comment: Thanks for your help, I still don't understand?

Comment: Please see my edit. Bottom line: the answer to your question is sumif. But, in order to use it, open_amount must exist.